# Compare 2 text files and export the matches Python

Tags: python

I currently have 1 text file (tab del) with 15,000 records.
I have another text file (tab del) with 5000 records.

In the file with 5000 records there are some row that match with the file containing 15,000 records. These are identifiable by a column header named URN (unique record number). for example i may need URN 62294 to be taken out of the main file, but i don't know i have to take that one out until i compare the two files and see that it is in both.

how difficult is this to do in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it difficult ? No, you could do it rather easily with

```
file1 = open("file1.txt","r")
results = []

for line in file1:
    file2 = open("file2.txt","r")
    for l in file2:
        if (l.split("\t")[0] == line.split("\t")[0]):
            results.append(l.split("\t")[0])
            break
    file2.close()
file1.close()

for i in results:
    print(i)
```

Now, is it the best way ? Probably not for large files.
(Took me 74 seconds with your files).

Comment: Wait OP shared the files?

Comment: No no, but I generated a couple of files with 10 columns and 15000 and 5000 lines respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pandas with `pip install pandas`

Then run this:

```
import pandas as pd

filename1 = #main file
filename2 = #the other file
main = pd.read_csv(filename1,sep='\t') # sep='\t' is for tab delimited file
side = pd.read_csv(filename2,sep='\t')
main['URN'] = main['URN'].astype(int)
side['URN'] = side['URN'].astype(int)
merge = pd.merge(main,side,on='URN',how='inner') #how=inner means the URN value is in both 2 files
#merge = merge[merge['URN'] != 62294]
print (merge)
merge.to_excel('Output.xlsx,index=False)
```

Comment: the thing is is that i don't know what URN i'm looking for. but if the URN is in both then i need it output into a new text file

Comment: I have updated the code to output the rows with URN value in both files. `how='inner'` is the inner join option.

Comment: this outputs a .xlsx file with nothing but headers in

Comment: @mbf94, try setting the column `URN` to `int` type then merge. updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library. It will allow you to load both tables as dataframes and join them on needed column in sql-like style. It should be rather easy with documentation.